# Sum in Oracle window function

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Can anyone tell me what is the significance of `sum` inside a `sum`  `(SUM(SUM(VAL)))` in the oracle partition, in the following code snippet

```
SELECT NMS,
       SUM(SUM(VAL)) OVER(PARTITION BY NMS),  ---- SIGNIFICANCE
       EMPNO,
       SUM(SUM(VAL)) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPNO)   ---- SIGNIFICANCE
  FROM PART_TEST_PART
 GROUP BY NMS, EMPNO;
```

Answer (score 6):

its calculating the total SUM of `VAL` per `NMS` (for the first one) and `EMPNO` (for the second one).

the group by + SUM(VAL) is evaluated first, then the analytics compute on that result.

e.g. if you had the result after the group by of

```
EMPNO  NMS SUM(VAL)
1      a   15
1      b   24
2      a   50
```

you'd have `SUM(SUM(VAL)) OVER(PARTITION BY NMS)` as

```
EMPNO  NMS SUM(VAL) SUM(SUM(VAL)) OVER(PARTITION BY NMS)
1      a   15       65  (15+50 for NMS = a)
1      b   24       24  (24 for NMS = b)
2      a   50       65  (15+50 for NMS = a)
```

you'd have `SUM(SUM(VAL)) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPNO)` as

```
EMPNO  NMS SUM(VAL) SUM(SUM(VAL)) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPNO)
1      a   15       39  (15+24 for EMPNO = 1)
1      b   24       39  (15+24 for EMPNO = 1)
2      a   50       50  (50 for EMPNO = 2)
```

Comment: A complete description is available here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407 and here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG021